# Tag Div impossible to locate the next element, via jquery

Tags: php, jquery

Friends, I have the following question:

The following code below finds the next element from the clicked select:

```
<div class="caixa-dependentes2">
  <select name="campo0[1]" id="campo0[1]" class="form-control aa" required>
  <option value="Habilitado">Habilitado</option>
  <option value="Desabilitado">Desabilitado</option>                                                  
  </select>
  <input name="campo1[1]" class="bb" value="teste1" />
  <input name="campo2[1]" class="cc" value="teste2" />
  <br><br>
  <select name="campo0[2]" id="campo0[2]" class="form-control aa" required>
  <option value="Habilitado">Habilitado</option>
  <option value="Desabilitado">Desabilitado</option>                                                  
  </select>
  <input name="campo1[2]" class="bb" value="test3" />
  <input name="campo2[2]" class="cc" value="teste4" />
</div>
```

It works perfectly.

The problem is that by including the divs formatting daughters in the field, it can not find more the next element, showing them as `undefined`, please see the code:

```
<div class="caixa-dependentes2">
  <div>
    <select name="campo0[1]" id="campo0[1]" class="form-control aa" required>
    <option value="Habilitado">Habilitado</option>
    <option value="Desabilitado">Desabilitado</option>                                                  
  </select>
  </div>
  <div><input name="campo1[1]" class="bb" value="teste1" /></div>
  <div><input name="campo2[1]" class="cc" value="teste2" /></div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div>
    <select name="campo0[2]" id="campo0[2]" class="form-control aa" required>
    <option value="Habilitado">Habilitado</option>
    <option value="Desabilitado">Desabilitado</option>                                                  
    </select>
  </div>
  <div><input name="campo1[2]" class="bb" value="test3" /></div>
  <div><input name="campo2[2]" class="cc" value="teste4" /></div>
</div>
```

My jquery:

```
$('.caixa-dependentes2').on('change', '.aa', function(){
    var proximo = $(this).nextAll('.bb').eq(0).val();  
    alert(proximo);
});
```

What was the mistake I made?

Comment: Your input is now nested within a div, `nextAll()` will match sibling elements. You may need to iterate over siblings and use `find()` till you have your next match. Otherwise start using explicit references.

Comment: Please include your code here, don't link to it. Make sure everything is in one place. That way it's easy for people to see the full picture. The question even makes sense if the other site removes the linked content.

Answer (score 0):

You can find next `.bb` element this way (not impossible, but EZ with jQuery):

```js
$('.caixa-dependentes2').on('change', '.aa', function(){
    /* your select element > one parent > next sibling > find .bb */
    var proximo = $(this).parent().next().find('.bb').val();  
    alert(proximo);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="caixa-dependentes2">
    <div>
        <select name="campo0[1]" id="campo0[1]" class="form-control aa" required>
            <option value="Habilitado">Habilitado</option>
            <option value="Desabilitado">Desabilitado</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input name="campo1[1]" class="bb" value="teste1" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input name="campo2[1]" class="cc" value="teste2" />
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div>
        <select name="campo0[2]" id="campo0[2]" class="form-control aa" required>
            <option value="Habilitado">Habilitado</option>
            <option value="Desabilitado">Desabilitado</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input name="campo1[2]" class="bb" value="test3" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input name="campo2[2]" class="cc" value="teste4" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Also on **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c96a4v0g/1/)**

I would also suggest you group/wrap the select box with inputs **[this way](https://jsfiddle.net/c96a4v0g/2/)**. That way you won't care where the `.bb` or `.cc` is located in document tree, you just go up to [closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) wrapper and [find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) the text input with class specified.

Comment: I saw that he finds the next element "bb". But when I tested the element "cc", appears as undefined. What is wrong?

Comment: "cc" is not next sibling, for "cc" you go `$(this).parent().next().next().find('.cc').val(); `. You should probably read the docs for jQuery's [next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/), [parent()](https://api.jquery.com/parent/), [closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) methods.